# Managing imports within a package

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I'm confused about how best to manage the following situation where multiple modules within a python package have the same dependencies.

Say I have a package `foo` whose file structure is

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    baz.py
```

and both `bar.py` and `baz.py` both require some other package, say `external_pkg`, so that they read

```py
# foo/bar.py
import external_pkg
def bar_fn(x):
   # do something with external_pkg
```

and

```py
# foo/baz.py
import external_pkg
def baz_fn(x):
   # do something with external_pkg
```

**Question:** Is there a way to refactor the package so that we can instead just include the `import external_pkg` line within `__init__.py`, rather than repeatedly writing it in the modules?  Naively removing `import external_pkg` from the modules and placing it in `__init__.py` leads to `NameError: name 'external_pkg' is not defined` errors.

This is obviously not a big problem in the above example, but I'm trying to write a small package where there are more modules and many more common imports involved.  I'm aware this might also just be a package design problem on my end.  I have tried to google this, but can't seem to find the right combination of terms to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foo/__init__.py:

```py
import numpy as np
```

foo/bar.py:

```
from . import * # or from foo import *

print(np.zeros(10))
```

Running (needs to be outside the foo directory for this to work):

`$ python -m foo.bar`

Output:

`[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`

Comment: Oh interesting, I had just thought to try `from .__init__ import *`, but that also led to errors due to later `from .bar export bar_fn` code in `__init__.py`, apparently.    Yours works, of course.  I don't really understand why, though. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: To be completely honest I don't know why mine works and other ways don't. I came across this problem a couple of times already and have trouble figuring out how to properly deal with it. I haven't found much good documentation, there are some examples in some random websites that helped me a lot. There is also the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html (go to 6.4 Packages)